# comparate a elementes inside of an array for get a specific value appscript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to do a comparate a elementes inside of an array for get a specific value, how i could do it with this?

```
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 var dataToImport = {};

 for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  dataToImport = {
  Nivel:data[i][0],
  Consumo:data[i][1],
  Flujo:data[i][2],

  if(dataToImport[Nivel]>99)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your looking for but hopefully this will help.

```
function myfunction()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataToImport = {};

  for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++) 
  {
    dataToImport = {'Nivel':data[i][0],'Consumo':data[i][1],'Flujo':data[i][2]}
    if(dataToImport['Nivel']>99)
    {
      Logger.log('Nivel greater than 99 dataToImport = %s', dataToImport);
    }
    Logger.log(dataToImport);
  }
}
```